# How to customize Date format in Exported CSV from Visualforce?

Tags: apex, visualforce, datetime, date, csv

I'm trying to build an export to CSV Visualforce page with dynamic fields that may include Date/Datetime fields in the output.

The trouble coming in my way is, if I don't format date/datetime fields, they get exported into a string with GMT text appended to it, which mostly is not what any external application would understand.

Next thing I tried was to use `format()` function in APEX and `<apex:outputText>` tag to output my Date and Datetime fields, but these also did not work, and they both are outputting Time component even for Date only fields.

Can anyone suggest what can I do to get my CSV file output to show Date in Date Only format and Datetime in Date and Time format?

One thing you would want to know is, I'm allowing user to select a Date Format before exporting, which may or may not have Time component in the format string. The Date format is a picklist so user can enter his preferred Date format string. The only issue is, if format has Date + Time component, then all Date values are also formatted with 12:00:00 as Time component value, which is not good.

VF Page:

```
<apex:page controller="ExportController" language="en-US" cache="true" contentType="text/csv#dataExport.csv" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
<apex:repeat value="{!columnValues}" var="c">{!c.label}</apex:repeat>{!NewLine}
<apex:repeat value="{!ExportData}" var="e">
    <apex:repeat value="{!columnValues}" var="c">
        <apex:outputText rendered="{!(c.datatype=='DATE' || c.datatype=='DATETIME') && selectedTemplateRecord.Format_Date_As__c != ''}" value="{0,date,{!selectedTemplateRecord.Format_Date_As__c}}">
            <apex:param value="{!e[c.name]}" />
        </apex:outputText>
        <apex:outputPanel layout="none" rendered="{!(c.datatype!='DATE' && c.datatype!='DATETIME') || selectedTemplateRecord.Format_Date_As__c == ''}">{!e[c.name]}</apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:repeat>
    {!NewLine}
</apex:repeat>
</apex:page>
```

In APEX Class the data is fetch like this:

```
public list<sObject> getExportData()
{
    String qry = 'select ' + fieldNames + ' from ' + objectName + ' where ID IN: recordIds';
    list<sObject> records = database.query( qry );
    return records;
}
```

Comment: Can you please paste some code snippets from your current solution/approach?

Comment: @Bachovski - I've updated my question with code details.

Comment: So if you stick `value="{0,date,dd'/'MM'/'yyyy}"`  instead of `value="{0,date,{!selectedTemplateRecord.Format_Date_As__c}}"` - what does that result in?

Comment: It would work, but the thing is we have only one option to format date/datetime. And the format string has date and datetime components both. If would be interetsed to know if there is some output field trick that I can sue in CSV output. Currently I tried outputField and it generated full HTML tags for each field ... that was un-necessary in CSV output file and broke full document ...